# Clipping elements causes children to lose preserve-3d transform style

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, transform, clip

I'm in a very specific situation for which I want a parent element to have a 3D transformation that wouldn’t be applied to its child.

I went for the solution that consists of a reverse transformation applied on the child to make it look as if it is not affected by its parent’s `transform`. It works fine.

http://codepen.io/tdm/pen/pgwbVY

However, and this is where it gets really tricky, I want to apply a mask on the parent using the CSS `clip()` property. And this, as it turns out, just [flattens the 3D context](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#grouping-property-values) of the child (so does `clip-path()`), which makes the reverse matrix go bonkers.

Do you guys see any other way I could make it look like the child doesn’t move while its parent is moving **and** while keeping both the parent and the child clipped according to the same cutting lines?